# fullcalendar html popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I've been thinking about this for a few days now, as well as checking SO and the API documentation, and I cannot figure out a way to use an HTML pop up box in the **FullCalendar API** on the "select" property instead of the current prompt to add an event. Is There a simple way to do this "without" using another plugin. Not that I am opposed to using a plugin, it just seems like a simple thing to do, but for some reason I just can't wrap my head around it.

**Edit**

What I would like to do...

1. When a day is selected a pop up box appears.
2. In the pop up box there is a form that allows me to add an event and description.

Help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so I was able to do it. start with a form in the body section...

```
<div class="popup"><h3>Add an Event</h3>
<form><div>Title: </div><input class="title" type="text" /><br /><br />
<a href="#" class="submitForm">submit</a></form></div>
```

Add a little styling...

```
.popup {
    background-color:ivory; border:1px solid gray;
    position:fixed; top:25%; left:25%; display:none; padding: 0px 20px 10px 10px; z-index:100;
}
.popup form div{float:left; width:80px; text-align:left;}
.popup form input{float:left; text-align:left;}
```

And submit the form like so...

```
select: function(start, end, allDay){
    $(".popup").show(); // show's pop up
    $(".title").focus(); // auto focus on the field
    var start = Date.parse(start) / 1000; // parse the start time to retain value
    var end = Date.parse(end) / 1000; // same but with end
    $(".submitForm").click(function(){ // on submission
    var title = $(".title").val(); // gets title value
    if(title != ""){ // if the title exists run script
        $.post("insertscript.php", {title: title, start:start, end: end, allDay: allDay}, // be sure to filter data 
        function(){
        $(".title").val(""); // clear title field
        start = ""; // clear start time
        end = ""; // clear end time
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        });
    }
$(".popup").hide(); // hide pop up box
});
},
```

Now I know that this is probably not the best way to do this, but it works and since I looked around for over three days to find the answer and no one else seemed to either have it or at least want to share it I finally buckled my seat belt and went on the ride myself. I hope that it helps someone:)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using jQuery UI?
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: I actually have looked at it, but my question is in regards to the actual pop up. I want to display a pop up that has a form so that I can POST a title to my db as opposed to the prompt box that is currently being used.

Comment: Do you have an example of how you're trying to complete this?

Comment: Similar to the google calendar. When you click on a time or day, it pops up a box with a form in it to post an event. I have the sql and php stuff functioning with the prompt, but I would like to add a description to the event without calling another prompt box.